# Error en la condición PHP no encuentra

Tags: php

Muy buenas tardes amigos, tengo la siguiente parte de mi código que se encarga de comprobar el tipo de formato de conversión de un archivo en CSV.

El problema es que cuando subo un archivo tipo Mac al momento de verificar en la condición si encuentra un carácter igual a los que están asociados en la variable: $search entonces el automáticamente debe reemplazarme esos valores para que se puedan cargar sin errores

Y si encuentra ese tipo de caracteres debería mostrarme el mensaje 'ENCONTRADO', pero no entra en ese ciclo a pesar de que estoy subiendo registros en el CSV que cumplen con la condición.

```
$l = trim($record);
            if (!empty($l)) {
                if (!mb_check_encoding($l, 'UTF-8')) {
                    if (mb_check_encoding($l, 'ISO-8859-1')) {
                        
                        $l = mb_convert_encoding($l, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
                        $search = array("ç", "‡", "ƒ", "Ž", "ê", "’", "î", "—", "ò", "œ", "„", "–");
                        $replace = array("Á", "á", "É", "é", "Í", "í", "Ó", "ó", "Ú", "ú", "Ñ", "ñ");     
                        $linea = str_replace($search, $replace, $l);
                        $flag = false;
                        

                        foreach($search as $value){
                            $pos = strpos($l, $value);
                            \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("ele ".json_encode($l));
                            
                            if($pos != false){
                                $flag = true;
                            }else{
                                $flag = false;
                            }
                        }


                        if($flag === true){
                            \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("ENCONTRADO");
                        }else{
                            \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('logger')->log("NO ENCONTRADO");
                        }
```

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Como sabes que no entra en el if del flag? .. Si haces un echo a flag, dentro del foreach, cual es el último resultado que te entrega ?

Comment: El ultimo resultado que entrega es false, pero el primero debería imprimir true porque el archivo CSV tengo como primera fila: (Aœat) lo cual es un caracter especial que deberia reemplazar.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($value);` dentro del `foreach` y verifica los datos. A veces uno cree que los valores deben ser los que uno cree, pero la realidad es otra. Estamos ante un problema de depuración. Cuando algo no funciona, depura, verifica los datos y comprueba si son lo que realmente crees que son. Ya nos contarás.